# Is First Order Stochastic Dominance (FOSD) relation convex?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, decision-theory, theory, probability

A convex relation is that $x\succeq y$ implies $\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y\succeq y$.

Let $>_{FOSD}$ be $\succ$, is the FOSD convex? Intuitively it seems convex.

Comment: By FOSD do you mean "first order stochastic dominance"? If so, the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, I can think of no other relation commonly referred to as FOSD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first order stochastic dominance relation is convex.

An easy way to prove this is to use the property that a cdf $F$ FOSD another cdf $G$ if and only if $F(x)\le G(x)$ for all $x$. That is, $F$ FOSD $G$ if and only if the graph of $F$ is never above the graph of $G$. It is then easy to show that $F$ is never above any convex combination $H(x)=\alpha F(x)+(1-\alpha)G(x)$, which in turn is never above $G$.